# One time boot into Read Only?

Tags: linux, grub

I'm trying to boot into read only mode to test some software.  I don't want to remount a drive after booting as that would not meet the requirements to test the software which checks the file system at boot.

Is there a way to do this without editing grub.conf?  Preferably adding something via the grub UI when interrupting boot?

If I do edit the grub.conf to boot in read only, how am I supposed to edit it back?

---

I understand that the kernel mounts root as RO but it's remounted as RW later in the boot process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `grub` is running, you typically have *some* ability to edit the kernel command line before `grub` loads the kernel and continues booting. Perhaps your distribution has [hidden the `grub` interface at boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode) -- holding down the left <kbd>shift</kbd> may bring it up and let you edit the kernel command line.

The Linux kernel `Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt` documents the `ro` kernel command parameter to mount your root filesystem read-only. If you add-in `init=/bin/sh`, then you'll be in charge of mounting whatever filesystems you want. You may need to mount `/proc` before `mount(8)` will show any mounted filesystems: `mount -t proc none /proc`.

Just be sure to give the `-o ro` or `-o rw` option to `mount(8)` as your mount each filesystem as you desire.

But I have to think there are better ways of testing software. What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: I don't want to fake this in software.  I want the software to detect booting into read only.

So I tried this (init=/bin/sh) and it looks like several things were mounted automatically anyway, including /dev/sda1 as /.

Comment: Btw, I'm running Red Hat, and I do have access to mid-boot grub modification.  Perhaps that wasn't correct/clear when I said "Is there a way to do this without editing grub.conf? Preferably adding something via the grub UI when interrupting boot?

Comment: You can edit the kernel command line at grub to your heart's content without ever once modifying the `grub.conf` file. All your edits from within the grub menu / command line interface only effect that single boot. If you want to add `ro` to a new `grub.conf` entry to make it _easily_ selectable, that's fine too. Up to you. :)

Comment: @neuroelectronic: can you add some context to that spreadsheet?

Comment: it was a copy/paste from the wrong buffer. you can ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done by adding

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

to your grub.cfg . Then you can create 2 different GRUB entries to the bootloader (eg. "RedHat" and "RedHat RO". The set the default entry like this in your terminal

```
grub-set-default "RedHat"
```

To run the other grub entry only for the next reboot issue in your terminal

```
grub-reboot "RedHat RO"
```

This works essentially, by adding a flag in the grub configuration (grubenv) and removing it after reboot. So basically your /boot/ partition has to be writeable. You can also remount the boot partition writeable if necessary. In any case you need the /boot/ directory on a separate partition.

Another alternative would be to put the boot partition on a USB stick and boot the "RedHat RO" from there every time you need it.

Otherwise: As sarnold already said: The changes you do in the GRUB command line or GRUB editing are only temporary.